# JBoss Application Server Log Configuration

Tags: jboss, log4j

Is there any configuration for JBoss Application Server's Log configuration
where in the logs get deleted automatically if the log size exceeds some threshold or if it is older than a certain date ?

Comment: This is a log4j question, not JBoss-specific.

Answer (score 1):

I believe there is no way to delete them, but you could use the `RollingFileAppender`. There, you can specify the file size limit like:

```
<param name="MaxFileSize" value="1000KB"/>
```